# Data structure to show number of visitors in a profile page by day wise

Tags: database-design, data-structures

I have a requirement to show how many visitors visit a profile in a graphical way, that can be represented by day wise or monthly wise. Can you suggest me what kind of Data structure will perfectly fit in to it. How I can fetch it fast if I stored in RDBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the data is stored in a relational database, there are likely built in date and time functions, which can be used in conjunction with a groupby clause to give you the flexibility you desire. For mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
you can use the Month() function on a date. You simply have to store the full date in the proper format for your rdbms.

Comment: yes. it is a good reference. day wise should be shown for only 15 days. Thought of running a job every 15 days and group the monthly count and move to another table so the performance won't affect much.